# Calling Functions using Objective-C and C++

Tags: objective-c, function, methods

Alright, I'm trying to call a function in xcode but apparently it isn't working. I made an objective-c class, and typed in the following code into the implementation file:

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

void printthis()
{
    NSLog(@"Hi, I have been printed");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        printthis();

    }
    return 0;
}



@end
```

Apparently, it returns the following error in xcode:

```
    ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error:
    linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you already have a main function somewhere else (probably main.m ?). If so the linker got confused -- you are not supposed to have duplicates of main function

Comment: Actually thanks, I had a main.m file with the main function as well.